# Accessing Inherited subclass in a different package

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, android-library

```
package 1; // this is a dependency library

public class A{

public String getName(){
return "In func getName, class A";
}

}

-------------------------------------------
package 2; // this is the library which I am building
import 1;

public class B extends A{

}

----------------------------------------------
package 3; // this is the app which is using the library which I am building
import 2;

public class C {

B b = new B(); // throws error here, says "Cannot access A"
b.getName();
}
```

this throws an error `B b = new B();`
I am not sure what is the issue here, this should work fine right?

I am working on building a library where I am extending a class from dependency library class. Now I am using the library which I built in an app and when I try to access the inherited class it throws an error.

I added dependency library as following in the library I am building

`implementation ':dependencyLibrary'`

In the app using my library

`include ':mylibraryName'
implementation project(':mylibraryName')`

I just don't want the 'dependencyLibrary' accessible to the app

Comment: You should mention the exact  Exception thrown - to help others help you.

Comment: says "Cannot access class A"

Comment: the example you have given works just fine. please check your directory structure to insure that your files are located in correct directories.

Comment: It is not about inheritance problem. It is about accessing the class without including the `dependencyLibrary`. In android when you generate `aar` from your `library`, it won't include the sources of dependent modules included in your `'library`. There are two ways to do this. First one is, you can generate `fat aar` which has both sources of your `library` and `dependencyLibrary`. Second one is, you must include `dependencyLibrary` in `app` along with your `library`. It is absolutely **impossible** to do it without these two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this error because you have not linked your library to your current project.
You need to link the library project to your current project so that the import statement works.

One way of doing this is by:

1. Go to File -> New -> Import Module ->
2. Add library to include section in settings.gradle file and
   sync the project (After that you can see new folder with library
   name is added in project structure)

> include ':mylibraryName'

3. Go to File -> Project Structure -> app -> dependency tab -> click on
   plus button
4. List item

Select module dependency -> select library (your library name should
    appear there) and put scope (compile or implementation)

5. Add this
   line in build.gradle in app level module in dependency section

> ```
> implementation project(':mylibraryName')
> ```

Comment: I did that already.

I added dependency library as following in the library I am building

>implementation ':dependencyLibrary'

In the app using my library
>include ':mylibraryName'
> implementation project(':mylibraryName')

I just don't want the 'dependencyLibrary' accessible to the app